# Easily Select users from a certain list for messaging - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am a newbie with iOS and objective-C. I am writing an app in which a user can send a message to a certain set of friends (selected from a list of Facebook friends which I am able to get).

I would like to enable the user to easily select friends from this list -> Have a "To" box (similar to how one types in an email and email addresses with a name as what user types appears -> user selects one of the email id's presses enter and then can add more similarly). This is not an email (and neither will the message be sent to Facebook).

How do I develop the code(UI) such that it is very easy for the user to select friends from this list as one does while typing emails (or sending Facebook message on iPhone)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might be looking for [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)?

Comment: Thanks everyone. There were a couple of options that I could use based on different posts I read: Three20 [link](http://three20.info/) - ttpickertextfield or APTokenField [link](https://github.com/arashpayan/APTokenField).. i ended up using APTokenField as it is very lightweight. I tried to make Three20 to work but without much success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could either use a UITableView populated by contact names obtained through the [Address Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html) framework or just use the [Address Book UI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html) framework.

Comment: Thanks everyone. There were a couple of options that I could use based on different posts I read: Three20 [link](http://three20.info/) - ttpickertextfield or APTokenField [link](https://github.com/arashpayan/APTokenField).. i ended up using APTokenField as it is very lightweight. I tried to make Three20 to work but without much success.